# Highlight multiple keywords in a string ignoring the added HTML in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have an extension that loops through a string to find all instances of any number of keywords (or search terms). When it finds a match, it adds a span tag around each keyword to highlight the keywords on display.

```
        public static string HighlightKeywords( this string input, string keywords )
    {
        if( input == String.Empty || keywords == String.Empty )
        {
            return input;
        }

        string[] words = keywords.Split( new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

        foreach( string word in words )
        {
            input = Regex.Replace( input, word, string.Format( "<span class=\"highlight\">{0}</span>", "$0" ), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
        }
        return input;
    }
```

The method works well except when you use a search term that matches the added span tag.

Example of dodgy output:

> The string "The class is high"
>
> The keywords: "class high"
>
> Resulting dodgy HTML output: input = "The <span class='highlight'>classspan> is high"

So it is looks for the first keyword in the original string, adds the decorating HTML, then looks for the next keyword in the altered string, adds more HTML and creates a mess.

Is there any way to avoid the decorated keywords when searching for each keyword?

UPDATE:

Given that case-insensitivity is important, I explored various case insensitive replace methods with partial success. The search function worked by ignoring case, but returned the casing used in the keywords and substituted it into the original text e.g. a search for "HIGH" returns "The class is HIGH". This just looks bad.

So, I returned to using Regex (sigh). I managed to rewrite my extension as follows, which seems to work very well but I wonder how efficient this extension really is. I welcome any comments on improving this code or achieving this without Regex.

```
    public static string HighlightKeywords( this string input, string keywords, string classname )
    {
        if( input == String.Empty || keywords == String.Empty )
        {
            return input;
        }

        string[] words = keywords.Split( new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

        foreach( string word in words )
        {
            input = Regex.Replace( input, Regex.Escape( word ), string.Format( "<!--{0}-->", Regex.Unescape( "$0" ) ), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled );
        }

        var s = new StringBuilder( );
        s.Append( input );
        s.Replace( "<!--", "<span class='" + classname + "'>" ).Replace( "-->", "</span>" );

        return s.ToString( );
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered the HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: Even if there is no perfect answer, I see some good effort.

Comment: Please look at my answer. It does the job without having to resort to arcane coding like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple change:

```
public static string HighlightKeywords(this string input, string keywords)
{
    if (input == String.Empty || keywords == String.Empty)
    {
        return input;
    }

    return Regex.Replace(
        input,
        String.Join("|", keywords.Split(' ').Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))),
        string.Format("<span class=\"highlight\">{0}</span>", "$0"),
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Let `Regex` do the work for you.

With your input `"The class is high".HighlightKeywords("class high")` you get `"The <span class="highlight">class</span> is <span class="highlight">high</span>"` out.

Comment: This is very good, but searches on whole words only whereas my extension will find partial matches.

Comment: @Scho - What do you mean by partial matches? There doesn't seem to be any difference in terms of the words it would match.

Comment: Okay, try searching for the search terms "clas igh".

Comment: @Scho - My code gives `"The <span class="highlight">clas</span>s is h<span class="highlight">igh</span>"`. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I must apologise @Enigmativity.  Your code is brilliant. Not sure how I missed it.  I must have been testing the wrong snippet at the time. The only issue is if a meta-character is added to the search terms, Regex falls over. For example if you search for "clas hig [" it will error with an "Unterminated [] set". I tried adding Regex.Escape and Regex.Unescape, but I'm not entirely sure what I am doing here.

Comment: @Scho - I've fixed the code to properly escape the `Regex`. Have a go now. Feel free to up-vote and accept. :-)

Comment: I have to say @Enigmativity, your code is very clever and very clean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Little different approach.
Adding StringBuilder would be better!

```
  public static string HighlightKeywords(this string input, string keywords)
{
  if (input == String.Empty || keywords == String.Empty)
  {
    return input;
  }

  string[] words = keywords.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();
  string[] originalWords = input.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  input = string.Empty;

  foreach (var word in originalWords.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
  {
    input += words.Contains(word.value.ToLower()) ? string.Format("<span class=\"highlight\">{0}</span>", word.value) : word.value;
    if (originalWords.Length - 1 != word.i) input += " ";
  }
  return input;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach using StringBuilder, but it doesn't allow for a case-insensitive search.